# Closing a file in page_unload event if it is still open

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having issue with a web site. The work is to create tab delimited text file and upload it via web service.

I am creating the text file using 'Using' keyword.

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Till here it is fine in case of error also.
 but i submit it as follows

```
    request.FeedContent = File.Open(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/filename.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

feedcontent accept a stream.
now sometimes there is error (server error etc)
on that case the application start giving the error :-The process cannot access the file '\\user\htdocs\filename.txt' because it is being used by another process.
when ever we want to repeat the process.

the problem is amplified as the file is not closed the same day, and resubmission had to be done next day only.

how can i free the resources later say in page_unload event or by any other way?

Comment: May I see the full code?

Comment: Why don't you use using on File.Open as well? You need to release the handle to the file after opening it.